# Create binary table where the number of rows are values from a variable

Tags: r, binary

I have a dataset with a two variables with counts (var1 and var2), that represent alive individuals at two times.
I need to create a table with a new binary variable, where the number of rows correspond to the values of var1, and within this variable, I need to assign "1" depending on values of var2 (e.g. if there is a 10 in var1 and a 3 in var2, then I would need 10 rows, from which 3 rows have "1", and the rest have "0").
Any function that would help?
Thanks

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include sample data and expected output? Also, could you explain the logic more completely? You’ll likely get much better, faster help after these edits. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way quite similar to @Guillaume Mulier but vectorizing;

```
x <- data.frame(id = 1:3, var1 = c(10, 5, 1), var2 = c(3, 3, 0))

with(x, data.frame(id=rep(id, var1),
              mort=rep(rep(1:0, nrow(x)),
                       c(matrix(c(var2, var1 - var2), 2, byrow=TRUE)))))
#   id mort
#1   1    1
#2   1    1
#3   1    1
#4   1    0
#5   1    0
#6   1    0
#7   1    0
#8   1    0
#9   1    0
#10  1    0
#11  2    1
#12  2    1
#13  2    1
#14  2    0
#15  2    0
#16  3    0
```

Answer (score 1):

I may have misunderstood what you wanted but here is what I did:

```
exemple <- data.frame(id = 1:3, var1 = c(10, 5, 1), var2 = c(3, 3, 0))
apply(exemple, 1, \(x) data.frame(id = rep(x[["id"]], times = x[["var1"]]), 
                                  var_binaire = rep(c(1, 0), times = c(x[["var2"]], x[["var1"]] - x[["var2"]])))) |>
  do.call(what = "rbind")
```

It seems to do the trick, it creates a data.frame by repeating 1's and 0's with function `rep`. `Apply` is used with margin = 1 to perform rowwise operations. Hence `apply` create here a list with each element a data.frame with var1 lines and var_binaire = 1 var2 times. Then, `do.call("rbind")` combines all in a data.frame. Here is the result:

```
exemple
  id var1 var2
1  1   10    3
2  2    5    3
3  3    1    0
output
   id var_binaire
1   1           1
2   1           1
3   1           1
4   1           0
5   1           0
6   1           0
7   1           0
8   1           0
9   1           0
10  1           0
11  2           1
12  2           1
13  2           1
14  2           0
15  2           0
16  3           0
```

I thought it would be possible without apply, but I couldn't figure out how. Maybe a better solution will come up. I hope this helped.